# Camel Blueprint test cases don't work

Tags: eclipse, junit, apache-camel, blueprint

I have created a camel blueprint test case and it doesn't work. I got an Exception when I tried to run it. my IDE is eclipse.

**Test Case Class:**

```
 public class Test2 extends CamelBlueprintTestSupport {   

     private boolean debugBeforeMethodCalled;
     private boolean debugAfterMethodCalled;

     // override this method, and return the location of our Blueprint XML file to be used for testing
     @Override
     protected String getBlueprintDescriptor() {
         return "OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml";  
     }

     // here we have regular JUnit @Test method
     @Test  
     public void testRoute() throws Exception {
         // set mock expectations
         getMockEndpoint("mock:a").expectedMessageCount(1);

         // send a message
         template.sendBody("direct:start", "World");

         // assert mocks
         assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

         // assert on the debugBefore/debugAfter methods below being called as we've enabled the debugger
         assertTrue(debugBeforeMethodCalled);
         assertTrue(debugAfterMethodCalled);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isUseDebugger() {
         // must enable debugger
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     protected void debugBefore(Exchange exchange, org.apache.camel.Processor processor, ProcessorDefinition<?> definition, String id, String label) {
         log.info("Before " + definition + " with body " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
         debugBeforeMethodCalled = true;
     }

     @Override
     protected void debugAfter(Exchange exchange, org.apache.camel.Processor processor, ProcessorDefinition<?> definition, String id, String label, long timeTaken) {
         log.info("After " + definition + " with body " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
         debugAfterMethodCalled = true;
     }
    }
```

**Maven Dependencies**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipse-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0.fuse-71-047</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Exception I got **

```
Unable to start bundle: 68
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to start bundle
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:144)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.startBundles(PojoSR.java:406)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.<init>(PojoSR.java:323)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.newPojoServiceRegistry(PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:134)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin: method <init>()V not found**
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.JUnitCorePlugin.<init>(JUnitCorePlugin.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:130)
    ... 33 more
```

could you please advise?

I got this Exception when I removed the eclipse runtime dependency

```
Unable to start bundle: 68
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to start bundle
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:144)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.startBundles(PojoSR.java:406)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.<init>(PojoSR.java:323)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.newPojoServiceRegistry(PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:134)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/Plugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:130)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 46 more
```

Regards,
Eman Azmy

---

I got this exception when I removed the osgi dependencies

```
Unable to start bundle: 36
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to start bundle
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:144)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.startBundles(PojoSR.java:406)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.<init>(PojoSR.java:323)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.newPojoServiceRegistry(PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:134)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/service/log/LogService
    at org.apache.geronimo.mail.Activator.start(Activator.java:52)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:132)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.service.log.LogService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 35 more
Unable to start bundle: 66
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to start bundle
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:144)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.startBundles(PojoSR.java:406)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.<init>(PojoSR.java:323)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.newPojoServiceRegistry(PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:134)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/Plugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:130)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 46 more
```

these are all dependencies I have

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.syngenta.mint.msgpublisher</groupId>
            <artifactId>client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.syngenta.mint.msgpublisher</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0.redhat-60024</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- needed dependencies for Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0.redhat-60024</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0.redhat-60024</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end needed dependencies for Camel -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0.fuse-71-047</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the eclipse runtime dependency, which you should remove from your pom.xml.

Comment: I added above the Exception that I got when I removed the eclipse runtime dependency

Comment: Ah remove the osgi dependencies as well. You just need camel-test-blueprint.

Comment: I added Exception that I got when I removed the osgi dependencies in the answer 2

Comment: You are mixing 2 different Camel versions. Make sure to only use the SAME version in your pom.xml, eg ending with 60024

Comment: You are using CXF in your test which can be a bit problematic. See these tests from Camel how to exclude some dependencies etc: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/tests/camel-blueprint-cxf-test

Answer (score 0):

Start small with the test examples provided at [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/blueprint-testing.html) (this seems to be your starting point anyway) and then add your dependencies and your routes one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the version of  camel-test-blueprint dependency to 2.10.0 rather than 2.10.0.redhat-60024 and I got the same exception but the test case ran successfully.

I'm not able to justify this case and I don't know the root cause of the Exception
Thank you Claus and Peter for your effort.

Regards,
Eman Azmy